# how to handle firebaseauth token expiration?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use firebase 2 years so far and was never clear to me how to handle firebasse auth token expiration.

I'm using android and once i do `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCustomToken(token);` interanally firebase receives a message like that:

```
{
   "t":"d",
   "d":{
      "r":5,
      "b":{
         "s":"ok",
         "d":{
            "auth":{
               "uid":"test",
               "token":{
                  "exp":1592230969,
                  "user_id":"test",
                  "iat":1592227369,
                  "sub":"test",
                  "aud":"test",
                  "auth_time":1592227369,
                  "iss":"https://securetoken.google.com/igibo-b0b27",
                  "firebase":{
                     "identities":{

                     },
                     "sign_in_provider":"custom"
                  }
               },
               "provider":"custom",
               "user_id":"test"
            },
            "expires":1592230969
         }
      }
   }
}
```

after this request any future calls to `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` will return info about this authenticated user.
It is clean in this json that this auth token expires sometime, but it isn't clear to me what will be firebase behaviors for that...

will `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` return null after token expiration?
will firebase automatially renew the token so it never expires?
if i need to monitore and revalidate token manually HOW I DO THAT?

if im not debugging i cant even find the information of expiration anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Firebase Authentication tokens expire an hours after they are created. Firebase SDKs automatically refresh the token after about 55 minutes, which means you usually don't have to do anything yourself. The current user will only become null if the token can't be refreshed, for example if the account has been disabled on the server.

Comment: what if this happens: 1- new token 2- user gets offline during 1 hour, 3- user become online again... will firebase ensure that the next request will only be delivered after the token renew? or will it face a race condition?

Comment: Firebase will refresh the ID token before sending operations to other services (such as Realtime Database, Cloud Firestore, or Cloud Storage). Give it a try, and report back if you have problems getting it to work.

Comment: I use firebase over 2 years so far without any major problems but sometimes i got some "permission denied" on database reads from users in prod that i find weird so im trying to find possible explanations to that. the race condition during the token renew would be a good one

Comment: btw this would be a very complicated test to try without being inside firebase team

Comment: There is a 5m window between when the client starts to refresh the token and when it expires. It *is* of course possible that the token expires before the refresh succeeds, but in that case I'd expect the client to explicitly flag the user as signed out (i.e. by firing its `onAuthStateChanged` event and by setting the `currentUser` to null).

Comment: I'm sorry i didnt understand. can we use 'FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener' to listen to token expiration? if so how?