# How to change the expiration time of the firebase token in an app with flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working on an app using Flutter, my intention is to use the libraries provided by Firebase for Flutter, not to create my own system for handling authentication. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62389267/how-to-handle-firebaseauth-token-expiration) answer, but testing, I logged in, waited 1 hour and when I tried to change the password I got the error: `requires-recent-login` described [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updatePassword.html). The token did not update until I logged in again. Is there already a way to increase the expiration time of this token or to know if the token is still valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase raises the `requires-recent-login` error when you try to perform a sensitive operation and the user hasn't signed in recently enough to securely perform that operation.

While the Firebase Authentication SDK auto-updates its ID token behind the scenes. But refreshing an ID token does not change the last login date of the user, so makes no difference to the `requires-recent-login` message you're getting.

If you get the `requires-recent-login` message from Firebase, the only solution is to ask the user to enter their credentials again and then retrying the operation.

Comment: And it's impossible to increase that time?

Comment: Because I feel that 1 hour is little time